# Cannot delete a particular command in history file

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I saw someone say can type `history -d<line number>` to delete particular command, but when I type `history -d<17>` want to delete line 17 which is named history, the system say **syntax error near unexpected token '17'**.
So, how can i solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXNpm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```bash
history -d 17
```

If you type `history --help` you'll see that:

```
-d offset — delete the history entry at position OFFSET
```